# Flutter - Firebase cloud functions call does not work on release mode

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, flutter-android

I'm working on a chat app, i created a firebase cloud function to set conversation messages as read.
It WORKS fine on debug mode on Android and iOS, on release mode works on iOS but NOT Android (Crashes the app).

Here's code and error messages.

Error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13774): FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
E/AndroidRuntime(13774): Process: com.domain.app, PID: 13774
E/AndroidRuntime(13774): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal class access: 'k.V.h.a' attempting to access 'k.r' (declaration of 'k.V.h.a' appears in /data/app/com.domain.app-SJSJSJSJ==/base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at k.V.h.a.a(Unknown Source:121)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at k.V.h.g.d(Unknown Source:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at k.V.h.j.a(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at k.V.h.g.d(Unknown Source:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at k.V.h.g.c(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at k.J.c(:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at k.I.a(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at k.V.d.run(Unknown Source:17)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(13774):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
E/flutter (13774): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/unavailable] UNAVAILABLE
E/flutter (13774): 
E/flutter (13774): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607)
E/flutter (13774): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167)
E/flutter (13774): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13774): #2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23)
E/flutter (13774): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13774): #3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:35)
E/flutter (13774): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13774): 
E/flutter (13774): #0      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:39)
E/flutter (13774): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13774): #1      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:35)
E/flutter (13774): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Dart code:

```
setMessagesAsRead(Conversation conversation) {

  FirebaseFunctions functions = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west1');

  HttpsCallable callable = functions.httpsCallable('setMessagesAsRead');

  try {
    callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
      'conversationID': conversation.getKey(),
      'userId': SS.getUserId(),
    });
  } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (e) {
    // Do clever things with e
  } catch (e) {
    // Do other things that might be thrown that I have overlooked
  }

}
```

Node.js code:

```
exports.setMessagesAsRead = functions.region("europe-west1").https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  const conversationID = data.conversationID;
  const userId = data.userId;

  //....

});
```

Internet permission is allowed in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried checking your androidmanifest if internet permission is allowed?

Comment: @KeiCredo Yes, internet permission is allowed